# why does adding uilabels to multiple subviews does not work?

Tags: cocoa, uilabel

Say,

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
....

[view1 addSubview:label];
[view2 addSubview:label];

Doesn't addSubview retain a reference to the current label? That is, it has its own copy of the UILabel but why the label only shows up on view 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not work because view can have only 1 superview. So if you want to have multiple instances of same label in different views you have to create a copy of your label yourself and add it to another superview.

Quote from reference:

> Views can have only one superview. If
>   view already has a superview and that
>   view is not the receiver, this method
>   removes the previous superview before
>   making the receiver its new superview.

Comment: hmm that's what im trying to avoid instantiate a nother uilabel but thanks for the explanation though.